# How to merge two numpy datasets based of index?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two large datasets and while pandas makes it easier to merge datasets, it uses too much memory for my use.  In pandas it would look something like this:

```py
left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
                     'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
                      'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                      'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})

result = pd.merge(left, right, on='key')
```

In this case the merge is simply concatenating two columns from the `right` data set, but this is usually used when the keys are shuffled.  How would I do this in Numpy?

Comment: Have you looked at `left.to_numpy()` and `right...`?  Do those arrays contain the information you need to 'merge'?  If the shape match, `np.concatenate` them, but that may not be what you want.  `numpy` doesn't have row or column names.

Comment: @hpaulj I was hoping to find something like this: `np.merge(left, right, index_col)` where `index_col` is the index of the column that I want to merge on.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: left = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
   ...:                      'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
   ...:                      'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})
   ...: 
   ...: right = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3'],
   ...:                       'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
   ...:                       'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})
   ...: 
In [4]: left
Out[4]: 
  key   A   B
0  K0  A0  B0
1  K1  A1  B1
2  K2  A2  B2
3  K3  A3  B3
In [5]: right
Out[5]: 
  key   C   D
0  K0  C0  D0
1  K1  C1  D1
2  K2  C2  D2
3  K3  C3  D3
In [6]: result = pd.merge(left, right, on='key')
In [7]: result
Out[7]: 
  key   A   B   C   D
0  K0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  K1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  K2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  K3  A3  B3  C3  D3
```

It would have been nice if you'd shown these dataframes.  That way we don't have to 'imagine' the result or run the code in our little heads :(

As I suggested, look at the arrays derived from the frames:

```
In [8]: left.to_numpy()
Out[8]: 
array([['K0', 'A0', 'B0'],
       ['K1', 'A1', 'B1'],
       ['K2', 'A2', 'B2'],
       ['K3', 'A3', 'B3']], dtype=object)
In [9]: right.to_numpy()
Out[9]: 
array([['K0', 'C0', 'D0'],
       ['K1', 'C1', 'D1'],
       ['K2', 'C2', 'D2'],
       ['K3', 'C3', 'D3']], dtype=object)
In [10]: result.to_numpy()
Out[10]: 
array([['K0', 'A0', 'B0', 'C0', 'D0'],
       ['K1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
       ['K2', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
       ['K3', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']], dtype=object)
```

If the keys match up we can simply `concatenate`:

```
In [11]: np.concatenate([Out[8], Out[9][:,1:]], axis=1)
Out[11]: 
array([['K0', 'A0', 'B0', 'C0', 'D0'],
       ['K1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],
       ['K2', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],
       ['K3', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3']], dtype=object)
```

`numpy` does not have a 'merge' functionality.  If the keys are simply reordered in one or the other, you could construct reorder the rows to match, e.g.

```
In [12]: Out[9][[3,1,0,2],:]
Out[12]: 
array([['K3', 'C3', 'D3'],
       ['K1', 'C1', 'D1'],
       ['K0', 'C0', 'D0'],
       ['K2', 'C2', 'D2']], dtype=object)
```

I'll let you figure out the reordering, including any missing or duplicate keys if needed. Since `pandas` already has worked out those kinds of details, it might not be worth your while to reinvent the wheel in `numpy` (especially if you aren't already proficient in `numpy`).